# Why do I get a Compile error Argument not optional when all arguments are specified and non-null?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project that looks something like this:

```
Function boi(sheet As Worksheet) As Scripting.Dictionary
Set my = New Scripting.Dictionary
'actually some stuff with the sheet
my.Add Key:="Foo", Item:="Bar"

boi = my
End Function


Sub test()
Dim tsheet As Worksheet
Set tsheet = Sheets("INPUT_OLD_DATA")
MsgBox (boi(tsheet)("Foo"))
```

When I try to run test(), it gives me a Compile error Argument not optional on the line `boi = my`. What I dont understand ist how there can be an Argument not optional error on a line where *no function is called*. As it doesn't actually get to the line `boi = my` I also don't think the error can be due to an invalid return.

I come from Python/Javascript/Java, please pardon me if this is an extremely noob question. :)

Comment: A few things spring to mind:  1) use option Explicit and Dim your variables.  2)  probably should be `Set boi = my` 3) way to many brackets in `MsgBox (boi(tsheet)("Foo"))`.  Use some intermediate variables,  and avoid the implicit forced `BayVal`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boi is an object so you must

```
SET boi = my
```